# Android Studio: I have 100 buttons and using an onclick function is it possible to get the ID that I specified for it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

I'm using android studio 3.6.X and I believe I am using API 15. I have 100 buttons all linked to an `onClick()` function. Each button is named `button_X` where x is the number of that button. The counting is starting from 1.

I was wondering if it would be possible to get the ID that I manually made for the button using `android:id="@+id/button_X"` once again, where X is the number of that button. I looked around Stack Overflow and Google for quite a while and I am unable to figure this out.

Thanks,
StealthHydra

Comment: Set the Tag of the buttons to their number. In onClick you can retrieve the Tag.

Comment: Why 100 buttons? That does not look good. Why not 100 items in a listview?

Comment: This is mainly for me to learn how to use android studio. Let me test out the Tag.

Comment: @blackapps how do I set a tag, It says to pick a resource?

Comment: button.setTag("mytag"); ?

Comment: Does it have to be a java program? If I want to change the tag in a xml file is that possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217473/discussion-between-stealthhydra-and-blackapps).

Comment: I dont know. Only if you can set a tag attribute there. Please try.

Comment: It says to create a resource. I will look around and if that doesnt work, then I will do some hard coding. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is probably not a great idea for production code, but if you're just trying to learn Android / Android Studio, I don't see any problem with it.

Your `onClick()` function receives a `View` parameter, and you can get the id from that:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int viewId = v.getId();
}
```

This `viewId` will be a seemingly-random number. Not helpful yet. But you can convert that number into the *resource entry name* like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int viewId = v.getId();
    String viewIdName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(viewId);
}
```

Now the value of `viewIdName` will be `"button_1"` or `"button_45"`, etc. You can then use the `split()` function to extract just the numeric portion:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int viewId = v.getId();
    String viewIdName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(viewId);
    String buttonNumber = viewIdName.split("_")[1];
}
```

If you need to convert the string (`"1"` or `"45"`, etc) to an `int`, you can use `Integer.parseInt()`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int viewId = v.getId();
    String viewIdName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(viewId);
    String buttonNumber = viewIdName.split("_")[1];
    int buttonNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(buttonNumber);
}
```

Comment: Very nice indeed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

### Create a custom button widget

First create a Button Widget that takes button number in its constructor.
Now this button number will be stored in the button widget

```
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget            // widget

MyButton({@required this.buttonNumber});          // constructor
```

### Create a Button List

You will need a List of Button Widgets using a for loop add new button widgets to
the list and give the index to the constructor of button.
You can use this list in columns or rows or even use individual buttons using an index.

> List buttonList();

### Create a Press Event

Made an event function that take button number as an argument.

> void buttonEvent(int buttonNumber)

Now you have the button number in the onPress event.

This is an example for your reference.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void buttonEvent(int buttonNumber) {
  print('Button no $buttonNumber was pressed');
  // Addition Functionality
}

List<MyButton> buttonList() {
  List<MyButton> myButtonList;

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    myButtonList.add(MyButton(
      buttonNumber: i,
    ));

  return myButtonList;
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final int buttonNumber;
  MyButton({@required this.buttonNumber});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text('Button $buttonNumber'),
      onPressed: () {
    buttonEvent(buttonNumber);
      },
    );
  }
}
```